# passing functor to function pointer

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [passing functor as function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840029/passing-functor-as-function-pointer)

I'm trying to pass functor to function pointer, but there is a compile error. How can I use this functor?

```
#include <iostream>

#include <QDebug>

class MessageHandler
{
public:
    MessageHandler(int val) : m_int(val)
    {
    }

    void operator() (QtMsgType type, const char *msg)
    {
        if (type == QtDebugMsg)
            std::cout << "Debug: " << msg << " (" << m_int << ")" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int m_int;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MessageHandler handler(5);
    qInstallMsgHandler(handler);

    qDebug() << "test";

    return 0;
}
```

qInstallMsgHandler's parameter is a typedef for a pointer to a function with the following signature:

```
void myMsgHandler(QtMsgType, const char *);
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the compiler error message?

Comment: One alternative is to wrap your handler object with a free function of the expected prototype. You would need to arrange for your object to be accessible from within the wrapper.