# C++ :: Capturing Lambdas

Tags: c++

I have a function that accepts a function pointer like so:

```
void invoke(void (*fnCallback)(int data)) { ... }
```

I also have a class method from which I would like to call this function, and pass the callback as a lambda:

```
void Class::testInvoke() {
  auto f = [](int data) -> void { data = data + 1; };
  invoke(f);
}
```

This works, but if I try capturing with the lambda, the code does not compile:

```
void Class::testInvoke() {
  int value = 1;
  auto f = [=](int data) -> void { data = data + value; };
  invoke(f);
}
```

In the second case, if I comment out the `invoke(f)` line, the code compiles. What am I doing wrong? How do I need to change the signature of `invoke` so it accepts captured lambdas?

Comment: Please include the compiler error message.

Comment: (related) [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840029/passing-functor-as-function-pointer]