# How do I create wrapper for a v8::Persistent<v8::Function> to a c++ function

Tags: c++, wrapper, v8

I have a `v8::Persistent<v8::Function>` that I need to turn into a `void(__cdecl*)` function. I was suggested to use a wrapper, but I'm unsure of how to do this.

Comment: Check [passing-functor-as-function-pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840029/passing-functor-as-function-pointer)

Answer (score 1):

For example like this:

```
v8::Persistent<v8::Function> func = ...;
v8::Persistent<v8::Context> context = ...;
v8::Isolate* isolate = ...;

void cpp_func(...) {
  v8::Local<v8::Context> ctx = v8::Local<v8::Context>::New(isolate, context);
  // The "this" inside the JavaScript function:
  v8::Local<v8::Object> arg_this = ctx->Global();
  // Arguments to the JavaScript function, of type `v8::Local<v8::Value>[]`.
  int argc = 0;
  int argv = nullptr;
  func->Call(ctx, arg_this, argc, argv);
}
```

There are many many more examples in V8's [test-api.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/master/test/cctest/test-api.cc).